# Two Wi-Fi adapters on a single chip

Tags: wifi

Are there any single chip solutions combining two Wi-Fi interfaces into a single chip?

I want to build a device which creates two Wi-Fi networks: the first is for the communication with a PC, and the second, as a client to the network router.

Comment: Just wondering why having both communicate via the router won't work for you?

Comment: Communicating via router requires configuring Wi-Fi authentication first, and I want to guarantee communication with the device, even before you know the Wi-Fi credentials.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Is the new device going to be passing packets from the PC through to the router and vice versa? Or does it do some other function, and needs to communicate first with the PC and then later with the router? In the latter case, why wouldn't a single reconfigurable WiFi interface be sufficient?

Comment: The 2nd case: I need to guarantee that a user will be able to change the properties of the device using Wi-Fi even when the router is offline. The device should also be accessible by CNAME, which means it has to run a DNS server and have a fixed IP.

Answer (score 3):

Many wifi chipsets can handle two networks simultaneously from the same chip (though they do have to be on the same channel).  I have an atheros chipset that presents two SSIDs in Master mode using hostapd on Linux.

Comment: I found some having in their specs something like "2x2 MIMO WiFi". Does "2X2" mean they support 2 independent network interfaces?

Comment: No, they don't need to be capable of MIMO.  Mimo allows the adapter to be on two channels at once, "doubling" the throughput.  2x2 just means it can both send and receive on both channels simultaneously.

Comment: thanks for clarification. Then it would be really helpful to see a short list of those "Many wifi chipsets can handle two networks simultaneously from the same chip". I heard about Atheros, but couldn't find anything else.

Answer (score -1):

There are dual band WiFi modules from Apple, but they are designed for MIMO applications. Yours seems to be from a single input, so why do you want to access two separate wireless gateway such as a wireless modem/router and a secondary wireless LAN router.

As others have suggested, isolation of two LO's and transceivers at these rates requires much experience as the proximity coupling effects will be significant and beyond the scope of this forum.  Apply has done it in a large module, which I suspect requires careful microwave combiners and will still be half-duplex.

"Based on the IEEE 802.11n specification, AirPort Extreme uses a technology called multiple-input multiple-output (MIMO) to transmit multiple data streams simultaneously. The result? AirPort Extreme delivers data transfer speeds up to five times those of 802.11g wireless networks — while achieving up to twice the range."